# iOS 6 Autorotation for Only SingleViewController in Multiple ViewController App

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios6

Is there any way to provide Autorotation to a `SingleViewController` as in our iPhone App have multiple ViewControllers and need to do autorotate for only One.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can use for your VC(not rotating)

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation

    {
        //return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
        return NO;
    }
// New Autorotation support for iOS 6.
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(6_0);
{
     Return NO;
    }
```

Also see [Apple Doc](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/RespondingtoDeviceOrientationChanges/RespondingtoDeviceOrientationChanges.html)
It will be helpful.

Comment: @BuntyMadan, Then you can use 
By checking the version
// New Autorotation support.
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(6_0);

Comment: Also check in appDelegate if not rotating.
//    [self.window addSubview:navigationController.view];
    [self.window  setRootViewController:navigationController];

Comment: I have UITabBarApplication and Added this in UINavigationController and set The navigationController on the Root.     self.window.rootViewController = self.navigationController;

Comment: as i can't understanding this new autorotation process.

Comment: Don't get confused with tabbar and navigation, its just for pushing/showing the ViewControllers on the app window. We have write the code in ViewController. shouldAutorotate is property of VC.

Comment: thanks a lot but please Do you have any Demo Project in with 2 ViewController there One is rotating and another one is not rotating. or do you explain me..

Comment: See [Apple Doc](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/RespondingtoDeviceOrientationChanges/RespondingtoDeviceOrientationChanges.html)
It will be helpful.